# How can i take inserted row id and update my next row using this id

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using two queries insert and update.
So i need when i making an insert to take output id from inserted row and to update another row using this id.

```
begin TRANSACTION;
insert into CustomerTrans (Username) values ('a') ; 
update CustomerTrans set Username='b' where TrnDocumentID=output (inserted.TrnDocumentID)
commit;
```

but i'm getting error output is not recognized

Comment: `OUTPUT` can only be referenced in an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement between the `SELECT` and `FROM` clauses, and it's not an object, it's a clause (I.e. `OUTPUT inserted.*`, notice that `OUTPUT` is a clause and `inserted` is the object). Could you be inserting more than one row at a time here, or only ever one?

Comment: Why would you ever need to do this? I'll guess that you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here because your code sample is inefficient and logical nonsense.

Comment: I found that i can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() . But the question is, do i have problem if i will have multiple clients which they will run same query at the same time?

Comment: No there would be no issue.  You can use Scope_Identity()  Apart from this also search output clause if you are going to insert multiple record then it would be helpful.